# check a checkbox when another checkbox is checked in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-functional-component, semantic-ui-react

I have three checkboxes, when one check box is checked, I want the second check box to be checked automatically. The below code is written in a modal. It will only set the state value, but the checkbox is not getting checked. The change will be reflected only when we close and open the modal again.

````
<Checkbox className="checkbox-wrapper" onChange={(e, data) => {
     if(data.checked){ 
       setAddAccessCheck( ...addAccessCheck,ga.groupId])
       setEditAccessCheck([...editAccessCheck,ga.groupId])
      }
      else{
       setAddAccessCheck(addAccessCheck.filter((add) => add !== ga.groupId))
       setEditAccessCheck(editAccessCheck.filter((del) => del !== ga.groupId))
     }
    }}
   value={addAccessCheck}
   defaultChecked={addSubmitAccessCheck.includes(ga.groupId) ? true : false}
 />```
````

Comment: Is your modal memoized to not render again for an update in the checkbox state? Also, where is the state for checkbox value/status stored? Will the changed value be passed into the modal?

Comment: Hi, did you mean to render the modal again when the state is updated? no, I haven't done that way. I'm not aware of that. is it because of that?